# Interpretation of logistic regression output with an interaction effect

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction, interpretation, lme4-nlme

I'm currently working on a research problem that requires the addition of an interaction term for each continuous covariate. In other words, I need to determine how the continuous variable changes across seasons (A = Fall/Winter, B = Preincubation, and C = Summer). I ran the following full model:

```
`results_full<-glmer(R0A1~MP_Scaled*Season+MPHW_Scaled*Season+HW_Scaled*Season+YP_Scaled*Season+Shrub_Scaled*Season+(1|ID)+(1|Year)+(1|Site),data=secondorder,family=binomial)
```

summary(results_full)`

The results are as follows:

[image]

I'm struggling with the interpretation of the results. How would you interpret results from an interaction between a continuous (MP_Scaled) and categorical variable (season)?

Example snippet of data: 
[image]

Comment: Are your effect variables properly coded?  The RE variances are zero...

Comment: Yes as far as I can tell. I provided a snippet of the data above to see where the variables are coming from. Does this make sense? I'm assuming the variation is not enough within the data set based on the random effects. This would be possible for ID and Year random effects but I would've expected some variation for site.

Comment: check the class.  I suspect that you've got them as numeric.

Comment: I checked the structure of the data using str(secondorder). Random effects: ID, Site, and Year are listed as integers. Is this incorrect? If so, how do you convert them to categorical values in R? Thanks!

Comment: Try this:  http://lmgtfy.com/?q=convert+integers+to+categorical+variables+in+R

Comment: I used your suggestion but received the same output as above. No variation for ID, Year, and Site. Not sure what else to do. Any other suggestions would be much appreciated?

Comment: strange.  if your data frame is `d`, what happens when you do `class(d$ID)`

Comment: class(d$ID) is equal to "factor"